# TabLayout indicator only slides betwee adjacent tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout

I've recently implemented the TabLayout within my AppBarLayout & CoordinatorLayout. It works fine except for one issue: the indicator doesn't slide to non-adjacent tabs. That is, when I tap on a tab that is not immediately adjacent to the currently selected tab it will hide and reappear under the newly selected tab. Is there something wrong I might be doing?

When looking at other Google Apps (i.e. Youtube) this is not the behavior I see. Instead I see the indicator smoothly slide over to the tab (even if it's not adjacent to the previously selected one).

Is there a way I can mimic the Youtube tab behavior?

Thanks

EDIT: 
I've created gifs of youtube tabs and my tabs. Notice how Youtubes tab indicator never disappears.

YouTube Tabs:

[image]

---

My Tabs:

[image]

Comment: default implementation of tab selection listener is setting attached viewpagers current item to the tab position if you haven't override anything check viewpagers adapter

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've added gifs of the animations. Notice how the tab indicator on youtube never disappears but on my app it does.